# System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am working on creating dictionary using SQLite. The configuration of my project is AnyCPU. The reference is nuget.

database creates in class DBRepository.
Code for its creation:

```
    //code to create the database
public string CreateDB()
{
    var output = "";
    output += "Creating Database if it doesn`t exist.";
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "ormdemo5.db3");
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
    output += "\nDatabase Created...";
    return output;
}
```

this method calls in mainActivity when my program starts.

I updated my Visual Studio and got an exception after I tried to compile my project.

Before updating everything worked perfect.

> System.DllNotFoundException: sqlite3

[image]

Comment: As SQLite is not part of the VS you should be more specific about how it is included in the project you are trying to compile after the update. The screenshot suggests it is not a compiler but a runtime error. I do not think your question provides enough information to receive good answers.

Comment: It looks like you are using System.Data.SQLite, right? Also, you don't use the mixed assembly, but the one with a separate native sqlite3.dll... How did you add the reference? Nuget or manually? What is the configuration of your project which uses sqlite (x86, x64, AnyCPU)? Too many questions, too little information...

Comment: I edited my question @galenus

Comment: I edited my question @kritzel_sw

Comment: @S.Koshelnyk it is not good enough, we still don't know what are the project properties, etc. I would suggest, based on the info you provided, to 'Clean' the solution and then 'Rebuild' it. Also, make sure, using the build output window, the sqlite3.dll is being copied into the project binary folder. If it isn't there, check what you have to change in order to make it appear there.

Comment: You mean bin folder? I have Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll.mdb in \Dictionary\dictionary\bin\Debug @galenus

Comment: This is not enough, there should be also the native 'sqlite3' dll. BTW, Do you develop for Xamarin or for desktop?

Comment: xamarin. I have downloaded sqlite3.dll file from the internet. I put it to my bin-folder and got an exception now. Also, I tried to clean and rebuild before it. It didn`t help me @galenus

Comment: Do you have any idea how to help with my problem? @galenus

Comment: It didn't work because it was Alpha. I downloaded Beta a few minutes ago and it works now. Thank you for trying to help me @galenus